# ListView Android, how to always show complete elements

Tags: android, listview

Is there a way to configure a ListView in such a way that it always shows the top element of the list on the screen complete?
In other words, whenever the list stops scrolling it should continue scrolling up or down until the element on the top shows entirely.

Comment: Do you mean first list item on the screen should be completely visible!! And why do you want to change default behavior of list view!!

Comment: There is nothing built in for this. Whether it is possible via re-scrolling the `ListView` when the touch event is completed, I am uncertain.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I actually solved like this.. but it jumps to the item instead of animating the sroll. Let me upload the answer.

Comment: If you are looking for another answer, you may have been better served by putting your own solution as an edit to your question, rather than as an answer.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I have just edited the answer with the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the issue.

```
    setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        boolean touched = false;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {           
            if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                touched = true;
            }else if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && touched){
                touched = false;
                ListViewWithSwipe.this.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        smoothScrollToPosition(getFirstVisiblePosition());  
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
```